# Struct cannot have a stored property that references itself

Tags: swift

I don't understand why I am forced to use a `class` instead of a `struct`

This works but I have to use a constructor:

```
class Token {
    var i: Int
    var prev: Token?
    var next: Token?
    init(i: Int) {
        self.i = i
    }
}
```

And this doesn't work giving the annoying message below.

```
struct Token {
    var i: Int
    var prev: Token?
    var next: Token?
}
```

> error: value type 'Token' cannot have a stored property that
>   references itself

Is there any reason for Swift to treat a `struct` differently?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191372/reference-cycles-with-value-types